# turning an array with two indexes into an object where {array[0] : array[1]}

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am trying to turn this:
`const arr = ['last_updated_epoch', 1669949100]` into

```
 {'last_updated_epoch': 1669949100}
```

I tried:

```
const arr = ['last_updated_epoch', 1669949100]

arr.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v}), {})
```

but i get this:

```
{1669949100: 1669949100, last_updated_epoch: 'last_updated_epoch'}
```

and I want to get this:

```
{'last_updated_epoch': 1669949100}
```

so i can push it in an empty array and use array methods

Comment: you can just do this `const obj = { [arr[0]]: arr[1] };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` especially when you need to translate lots of them.

```js
Object.fromEntries([['last_updated_epoch', 1669949100]])
// this would be {'last_updated_epoch': 1669949100}
```

Here is the MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have make things complicated,why not use `let result = { [arr[0]] :arr[1] }` directly?

```js
const arr = ['last_updated_epoch', 1669949100]

let result = { [arr[0]] :arr[1] }
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
for (let i = 0 , i < arr.length - 1, i++) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1]
}
```